# Anaconda : unable to open new jupyter notebook getting error: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When trying to create a new notebook an error popup says
'_xsrf' argument missing from POST

using anaconda navigator

Please help with this. I am not getting an appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: I am also getting same error. Thanks for posting this question